# pyspark save dataframe to hive table using variable in the name

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using databrick pyspark for coding
wondering how could I pass the **variable value** to the name of the table which I want to save in the Azure

I am able to use this if that is the fix table name

```
result.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("result0911")
```

but I hope to do this

Having a variable: `time = datetime.today()`
the value of that is "2019-09-11 12:10:48.969602"

I want to first format the "time" to `"20190911121048"` which is good for the name of a table (I need the time also, because people may save the records more than once per day)

then use that value `"20190911121048"` table name which I want to save
the table name should be `"result_20190911121048"`

any suggestion? Thank you 
the following does not work

```
result.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("result_%s time")
```

Comment: I am able to use {t=time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")} to reformat the time but still not abke to put the value of t in the name.

Comment: Make the variable of table name and then use str.format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have 2 variables having values

```
time = "20190911121048"
table_name = 'result'
```

Then you can make table name as :

```
final_table_name = '{}_{}'.format(table_name, time)

result.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(final_table_name)
```

Comment: @CloverCeline please let me know if this is what you were looking for and please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the input. I am able to use this:

```
time = datetime.today()
t=time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
result_name ="recommendation_%s" % (t)
final_recon.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(result_name)
```